# WebdriverIO test getting skipped, test migrated from protractor to WDIO

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, mocha.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I am trying to migrate my protractor framework to wdio. I have used wdio/codemod to migrate scripts. On running the migrated tests all are being skipped. Requesting all the help and ideas I can get around this.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the console log which also doesn't show any error -

```
PS D:\ProtractorMigration\wdioBase> npx wdio wdio.conf.js -v

Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-06-19T04:02:36.652Z

2023-06-19T04:02:36.773Z INFO chromedriver: Initiate Chromedriver Launcher (v8.1.1)
2023-06-19T04:02:36.775Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2023-06-19T04:02:36.808Z INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol
2023-06-19T04:02:36.814Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome (undefined) with flags: --enable-automation --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-rtection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/ --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-features=site-per-process,TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1200,900
2023-06-19T04:02:37.427Z INFO devtools: Connect Puppeteer with browser on port 64797
2023-06-19T04:02:38.086Z INFO chromedriver: Start Chromedriver (D:\ProtractorMigration\wdioBase\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe) with args --port=9515 --url-base=/
2023-06-19T04:02:38.153Z INFO chromedriver: Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9515
2023-06-19T04:02:38.154Z INFO chromedriver: Only local connections are allowed.
2023-06-19T04:02:38.155Z INFO chromedriver: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
2023-06-19T04:02:38.166Z INFO chromedriver: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
2023-06-19T04:02:38.249Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2023-06-19T04:02:38.251Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js,-v
[0-0] 2023-06-19T04:02:39.628Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
2023-06-19T04:02:41.609Z INFO @wdio/cli: [0-0] SKIPPED in chrome - file:///D:/ProtractorMigration/wdioBase/test/specs/lucaEnrollmentTests/luca_EnrollmentEnrollNewFamilyAutoDebitCreditCard_spec.js
2023-06-19T04:02:41.610Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2023-06-19T04:02:41.611Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 skipped, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:04

2023-06-19T04:02:41.615Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2023-06-19T04:02:41.881Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2023-06-19T04:02:41.882Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

Below is the config file I am using -

```
import { remote } from "webdriverio";
const params = require("./testData.json");
export const config = {
  // ====================
  // Runner Configuration
  // ====================
  // WebdriverIO supports running e2e tests as well as unit and component tests.
  runner: "local",
  injectGlobals: true,

  // ==================
  // Specify Test Files
  // ==================
  specs: [
    "./test/specs/lucaEnrollmentTests/luca_EnrollmentEnrollNewFamilyAutoDebitCreditCard_spec.js",
  ],
  // Patterns to exclude.
  exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
  ],

  // ============
  // Capabilities
  // ============

  maxInstances: 1,

  capabilities: [
    {
      // capabilities for local browser web tests
      browserName: "chrome", // or "firefox", "microsoftedge", "safari"
    },
  ],

  // ===================
  // Test Configurations
  // ===================

  logLevel: "info",

  bail: 0,

  baseUrl: "http://localhost",
  //
  // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
  waitforTimeout: 10000,

  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,

  connectionRetryCount: 3,

  services: ["chromedriver"],

  framework: "jasmine",

  reporters: ["spec"],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineOpts: {
    // Jasmine default timeout
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,

    expectationResultHandler: function (passed, assertion) {
      // do something
    },
  },

  // =====
  // Hooks
  // =====

  onPrepare: async function (config, capabilities) {
    // var runner = this.wdio;
    params, (global.params = params);
    // const browser = await remote({
    //   // WebdriverIO options
    //   capabilities: {
    //     browserName: "chrome",
    //   },
    //   logLevel: "info",
    //   waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //   connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    //   connectionRetryCount: 3,
    // });

    // this.wdio.on("fail", function (test) {
    //   // Do not skip failing tests.
    //   test.continue();
    // });
  },

  // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
  // },

  // onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) {
  // },

  // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
  // },

  before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    const options = {
      /* browser options */
    };
    const browser = webdriverio.remote(options);
    browser.init(); // initialize the browser
  },

  // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
  // },

  // beforeSuite: function (suite) {
  // },

  beforeTest: function (test, context) {
    const { remote } = require("webdriverio");
    const sync = require("@wdio/sync").default;
  },

  // beforeHook: function (test, context) {
  // },

  // afterHook: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
  // },

  afterTest: function (
    test,
    context,
    { error, result, duration, passed, retries }
  ) {
    if (error) {
      browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
  },

  // afterSuite: function (suite) {
  // },

  // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
  // },

  // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
  // },

  // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
  // },

  // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
  // },

  // onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
  // }
};
```